# Change the Next button of Gridview not fire pageindexchanging

Tags: c#, asp.net, aspxgridview, page-index-changed

I have a gridview which has paging property. From code behind i am changing the Next text with an image with the following code. the image is successfulu loaded instead of next text but when i am clicking it does not fires the event PageIndexChanging , but if i have the default text of the pager Next it does fires the event. Any help?

```
grdQuestions.PagerSettings.NextPageImageUrl = "NewImages/next_bg.jpg";
```

Comment: There shouldn't be anything wrong with that. Did you check for any errors in console?

Answer (score 3):

In the page load event you should check IsPostBack condition.
Like this

`if(!IsPostBack)
  {
     //page load events
  }`

try it now